# How to execute PowerShell script in Windows-container under Docker?

Tags: windows, docker, powershell

Below is my `entrypoint.ps1` (**PowerShell**-script):

```
Set-Location -Path C:\nginx
& "C:\nginx\Configure-Nginx.ps1"
& "C:\nginx\nginx.exe"
```

I need to my `Configure-Nginx.ps1` and `node.exe` were executed on `docker run` so I've put an entrypoint to my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nginx 
# nginx is a custom image that's based on mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809-KB5003171
COPY entrypoint.ps1 ./
COPY install/Configure-Nginx.ps1 /nginx/Configure-Nginx.ps1
ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "entrypoint.ps1"]
```

However my container begins to restart each minute... Well, I've decided there is a some error in the script then I run this image manually with `--entrypoint powershell` and executed my script in the console directly: `.\entrypoint.ps1`. The script was frozen (cuz `nginx` was launched) and I could connect to my container from web-browser on the host machine... So everything works! **Then why doesn't it work if I call my entrypoint from `Dockerfile`? What's difference?** Maybe someone has met a similar problem...

**P.S.** The container is based on `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809-KB5003171` with **PowerShell v5.1.17763.1852**

Comment: Could you please show us the whole Dockerfile? Also you can see logs by `docker logs <containerName>` maybe that could be helpful.

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş I've provided more details, unfortunately, I can't post a whole `Dockerfile`.

Comment: That's enough details, Check the workdir of the custom image. It is possible that teh scripts are not being copied over to right locations. By the way, it is not best practice to use the root as default workdir.

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş, all scripts are in right locations, I've checked already. And as I said it works if I run the script manually from container.

Comment: Did you try `docker logs`? Maybe add some `echo` in your scripts to make sure they are being run. Then you can see the output with `docker logs` or by running in attached mode. At least you can see if that's a problem with script or docker.

I am also curious, do you HAVE TO use Windows? If you have the chance, run to Linux

I don't have a choice, and I can guarantee this is only the beginning of your problems

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş, thank you for advice, that's my stupid mistake. I've checked logs before but I missed the container and watched logs for another container where all is ok. I've noticed it just now... The problem is that I've passed a wrong environment variable name in my `docker-compose.yml` (I forgot to change it to new version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firs make sure the script is available under the container root:

```
COPY entrypoint.ps1 /entrypoint.ps1
```

Then execute it either by `-Command` or `-File`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["pwsh", "-Command", "/entrypoint.ps1"]
ENTRYPOINT ["pwsh", "-File","/entrypoint.ps1"]
```

Comment: Ahh right, the powershell in newer Windows containers is called "pwsh"

Comment: Thank you, I gonna try

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help, I tried to add `-File` and `-Command` flags. Also I've specified a version of **PowerShell** in my question (**v5.1.17763.1852**) so there should be `powershell` name.

Comment: elaborate: is this script not running at all or it runs and exits prematurely? +1 `powershell` for v5

Comment: I marked yo answer as right cuz it is. Unfortunately, my real mistake was very stupid, I didn't notice that I was watching logs of another similar container and couldn't get why it restarts each one minute. I forgot to change env variable name in my `docker-compose.yml` but I used right one for manual test that's why everything worked.

Comment: environment vertigo happens to all of us... glad it worked for you